# check if process is UWP from python

Tags: python, c++, windows, uwp

I'd like to monitor processes which are UWP apps.
currently I'm checking it from C++ using the following code :

```
LONG PkgId = GetCurrentPackageId(&sz, buf);
return (PkgId != APPMODEL_ERROR_NO_PACKAGE);
```

Is there any way to automatically check this attribution from `python` or shell command-line ?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it turns out that I can use this API from C# code running on top of Powershell script.